# Can an immaterial being not be conscious?

Tags: theology

Is it possible for an immaterial being or object with causal powers to not be conscious? Or is this a contradiction?

The only immaterial being I can conceive of to have causal powers is a conscious, personal one. However, to create any sort of physical effect requires a physical body in day to day experience, so of course my imagination is limited. Thoughts?

Comment: Plato and Aristotle had richer imaginations. Not only did Plato's Forms have causal powers, they were the ultimate causes of everything in the physical world. Penrose and Tegmark, of the ["universe *is* a mathematical structure"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_universe_hypothesis),  fame are his modern descendants. [Aristotle's substantial forms](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/#SubsCausBein) likewise.

Comment: Each photon has causative powers because it interacts with other objects according to the rules of quantum electrodynamics. Photons have restmass zero.

Comment: @MarcoOcram Are you unaware of the semantic difference between "not material" and "imaginary"?

Comment: @user76284 yes, but imaginary is a subset of immaterial, and I want to know if that's what he meant!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you suppose that all immaterial beings with causal powers are conscious? Anyway, let's suppose that's the case.

To act in the physical plane, physical infrastructure (for example a body) is essential. I see three options :

- The being *possesses* a physical infrastructure (directly or indirectly  perhaps at a higher level).
- The being can *influence* a physical infrastructure (for example at the mind level).
- The being is *interacting* with physical infrastructure as part of its being, its role, it's topology.

*You could also be open to a multi-layer topology, where immaterial beings interact with each other in perplexing ways (like the ecosystem of a jungle for example), down to the physical level.*